# What private ip address space to use for a self-host VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ip, private

I have set up a private OpenVPN tunnel which uses the a 10.x.x.x private ip range as the client and server ip. I was wondering if that would cause any problem in big networks that use that ip range also, like for example hotels or conference networks.

I noticed trouble staying connected to the internet sometimes and I was wondering if that had anything to do with it.

What is the recommend ip address range to use in a VPN setup like this?

The setup is:
1 Server
2-3 Clients at once at most (I know that the IP range is overkill, but it was from a tutorial I did some time ago)
OpenVPN (if that is anyhow important)

Answer (score 4):

Any private range can conflict with a company’s internal range. You can try using the TESTnet ranges, e.g. 192.0.2.0/24 or 203.0.113.0/24, but even these can be used in some companies.

If you want to be sure there won’t be any addressing conflicts ever, you must use public IP addresses that you own.

Edit: limit the range as much as possible to decrease the chance of addressing conflicts, e.g. use a small random /26 range in the 10.0.0.0/8 network instead of the entire 10/8 range.

Comment: Even that *might* not save you - CloudFlare found some folks were using 1.1.1.1 internally when they launched their public DNS service and got conflicts.

Comment: Agreed. Cisco had a bad habbit of configuring their WLC authentication page with the address 1.1.1.1 and nobody cares to change that.